# Why the useState of react hooks is not updated when I change the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using hooks in react native.
And something happens, when I update a state the value is not assigned immediately.
This is my example code.

```
async function updateDeviceAdminAttributes(Token) {
    await getAdminAttributes(Token); //This function update objWithRPC
    if(objWithRPC != null) 
    {
      setDeviceAdminAttributes(objWithRPC);
      console.log(deviceAdminAttributes); //this return object {} 
    } else {
      setDeviceAdminAttributes({});
      console.log(deviceAdminAttributes); //this return  Object{ rpc1 : true }
    }
  }
```

I am working with react native and the **getAdminAttributes** function is a **GET** request from an API that updates the **objWithRPC** object. This function is activated when I change the value of a Picker (in app react native), change the value of the **picker** and it makes me the query that updates the value of objWithRPC. if the query does not contain data then it throws me a null if not then the object

This variable is updated correctly and when entering the conditional **if (objWithRPC! = Null)**
Enter the places that should go the problem is that there I update a variable through the **useState** hook.

Doing so **returns** `obj = {}`
and if I change the request so that it returns null there it should return obj = {} but now if it returns the previous object as it should be

Why is this happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately.

Comment: Thanks, the information was useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the change of state is asynchronous

If you want to track the change of state you can do so using useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(deviceAdminAttributes);
}, [deviceAdminAttributes]);
```

Comment: happy to help :)